# how to zoom and center the content of an iframe in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, iframe

So I have an iframe that contains a report. I am using the iframe as a report viewer.

I need to be able to zoom the contents of the iframe, and the zoomed result must be centered.

In chrome, IE, Edge this it works no problems, setZoom contains the percent to zoom, docLoad is the id of the iframe:

```
function setZoom() {
    var zoom = $('#setZoom').val();
    var doc = $('#docLoad').contents().find("body");
    doc.css('zoom', zoom);
    doc.css('-ms-zoom', zoom);
    doc.css('-webkit-zoom', zoom);
    doc.css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + zoom + ',' + zoom +')');
    doc.css('-moz-transform-origin', 'center top');

    DetectBrowser();
    if (isEdge) {
        var areas = $('#docLoad').contents().find("area");
        if (areas !== undefined & areas.length>0) {
            for( index = 0; index < areas.length; index ++) {
                var item = areas[ index ];
                var original = item.getAttribute("data-originalPoint");
                var splitted = original.split(",");
                var scalled = "";
                for ( i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( i != 0 ) scalled = scalled + ",";
                    scalled = scalled + splitted[ i ] * zoom;
                }
                item.setAttribute( 'coords', scalled );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in the case of Firefox the content is not centered but right aligned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just tossing something on the wall and hope it sticks.  Have you gone down the path of viewport hacks?  Do you know if the version of Mozilla Firefox support the zoom CSS property?

Comment: Yes, it does zoom, but it does not center. moz does not support the zoom, but it supports the transform. that is why: doc.css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + zoom + ',' + zoom +')');

Comment: Could you perhaps, create a function that will only fire for Firefox.  What it will do is gather all necessary measurements and give the body `margin-left` plus or minus the pixels needed to create the illusion being centered?